# FFTW and long double precision

Tags: c

I compiled the FFTW 3.3.5 libraries with (http://www.fftw.org/doc/Precision.html):

```
./configure --enable-long-double
make
make install
```

I compile the code below with `gcc -std=gnu99 main.c -o sample.x -lfftw3l -lm`

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI acosl(-1.0L)
#define FMODE FFTW_MEASURE

int main() {
  fftwl_complex  *A = fftwl_malloc(4096*sizeof(fftwl_complex));
  fftwl_plan     ft = fftwl_plan_dft_1d(4096, A, A, FFTW_BACKWARD, FMODE);
  long double    q, u, overN = ((long double) 1.L/4096);

  for (long int j = 0; j < 4096; j++) {
    q = 2.L*PI*(j*overN - 0.5L);
    u = 2.L*atan2l(0.5L*sinl(0.5L*q),cosl(0.5L*q));
    A[j] = -1.IL*cpowl(0.01L*(1.L/ctanl(0.5L*(u-0.1IL)) - 1.IL),2);
  }
  printf("%26.18LE\t%26.18LE\n", creall(A[1]), cimagl(A[1]));
  fftwl_execute(ft);
  for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++) {
    A[j] = -1.0IL*((fftwl_complex) j*A[j])*overN;
  }
  printf("%26.18LE\t%26.18LE\n", creall(A[1]), cimagl(A[1]));
  memset(A+2048, 0, 2048*sizeof(fftwl_complex));
  fftwl_execute(ft);
  printf("%26.18LE\t%26.18LE\n", creall(A[1]), cimagl(A[1]));
}
```

To my understanding the result of the final printf must be 
the same upto 17-18 decimal digits for all the runs, however 
what I'm getting is distinct in 14th decimal place. 
Something like this might indicate that a **long double**
was demoted to a **double** type. The output of the code 
changes from one run to another:

```
  2.907416794556517046E-07    9.025765251354815022E-05
 -5.697284273172913999E-04    7.463682637972633967E-24
  1.895341327532694420E-04    3.343168537700265992E-07

  2.907416794556517046E-07    9.025765251354815022E-05
 -5.697284273172913999E-04    1.965167197605865111E-23
  1.895341327532697672E-04    3.343168537692799396E-07
```

Any ideas on where I lost the **long double** accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each items of the array resulting from a complex FFT is [a weighted sum of the 4096 items of the input array](http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029) which can be computed in different ways. A study of the way the error propagates can be performed as described [here](http://www.tina-vision.net/teaching/cvmsc/docs/fourier.ps).

Since weights of the sum are always of norm 1, the variance of an item of the output array is the sum of the variance of the items of the input array (items of the input array being considered as independent random variables).

[image]

The precision 1e-18 is the ratio of the standard deviation to the norm of the value. Hence, if long double are used:

[image]

Finally, the precision of the result writes:

[image]

A direct consequence of this equation is the phenomenon of catastrophic cancellation: the standard deviation of the output is finite, but the value `|y|` is very small because similar value were substracted... As a result, none of the digits are significant! See here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) for instance. This explains why `7.463682637972633967E-24` can easily become `1.965167197605865111E-23` in your case. Indeed, if partial cancellation occurs, the precision can easily decreases from 1e-18 to values like 1e-14. Smaller values of |y| feature less significant digits.

The fact that the output is different from one run to another can be due to the use of the flag `FFTW_MEASURE`. If this flag is used, different algorithms will be tried and FFTW will choose the fastest one. Since 1D FFT of length 4096 are now very fast, the timing may not be very consistent and different algorithms of comparable performances can be picked. The different algorithms will lead to different computations and different outcomes for non-significant digits. Does these variations still exist if the flag `FFTW_ESTIMATE` is used instead? If this flag is used, [it seems that FFTW uses a simple heuristic to choose the algorithm](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html). It is likely that this heuristic is deterministic...